# Magento module can't see in the admin panel after installation

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I installed a module in my magento site. But after installation I cannot see it in the admin panel. Can anybody help me?
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-admin-payment.html

Comment: Did you log out and back in to the admin panel after installation?

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to *System-> Cache management*: Clear all caches.
2. Log out and go to *System->Configuration-> Advanced*: Check to see that module is in the list of installed modules.

Comment: I installed it through Magento Connect. And it is enabled as well. I just need to know its usage. I can't see any menu option or something in admin panel.

Comment: It is used for creating orders quick via the admin panel when you want to avoid using worrying the specific payment method. Seems like it is sort of a place holder.

Comment: Thanks Gershon. But I didn't get you. Could you please explain?

Comment: You can find its settings under System - Configuration - payment Methods - Simple Payment Method for Admin

Answer (score 0):

I know this is answered, but here's another possible cause for anyone in the future finding this question.

It's possible that the store admin has set up user roles/permissions to only allow access to specific sections of the backend. I have installed modules and nearly gone crazy wondering why there are no backend config sections for the module, only to find out that the client has stripped some of my admin user's permissions.

So it's possible that some new modules will get installed without correct 'allow' rights for the currently logged in admin user.

Either set the roles/permissions to allow this, or if that isn't possible, you can find the config section's permissions in the database in the admin_rule table. Find the section you're trying to gain access to and change 'permission' from 'deny' to 'allow'.

Answer (score 0):

Module install after fire setup upgrade command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

After fire this command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

and check admin panel